# complicated sentence in python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I don't understand the following sentence's meaning in python,

```
if all(x not in z

       for x in y):
       ...
```

the original sentence is

```
if (all(dimQn not in cntx.qnameDims 

        for dimQn in (cntx.qnameDims.keys() - roleURIdims.keys()))):

        ...
```

Could you just tell me the logical relation of above sentence?

Comment: It's a complicated way of saying that the intersection of y and z is empty.

Comment: Even worse, in this example, `y == z - w` for some set `w`, which means it checks if the intersection of `z - w` and `z` (which is just `z - w`) is empty, which is only true if `z == w`. You could just write `if set(cntx.qnameDims) == set(roleURIdims)`.

Answer (score 2):

"If every value in `y` is not in `z`."

`x not in z for x in y` will generate a sequence of boolean values indicating whether or not each value of `y` is in `z` (`True` if the value is not in `z`, `False` if it is). Then the `all()` check requires all values of the sequence to be `True`, which in this case means all of the elements are not in `z`.

It is functionally equivalent to the following code:

```
for x in y:
    if x in z:
        break
else:
    # ...
```